# Function only working on first td's, but not for all the td's?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I used a resizing function in my table and its working fine. The problem is its working in the td's of the first row only. For other td's, its not working.

I tried of changing the width of the tr of the selected td and also tried of changing the table width also, but its not working. I dont know what is the problem with that.

The width for the corresponding td is calculated correctly while dragging, but its not applied on the td. But its working fine in the td's of the first row.

```js
var ob;
    var obLeft;
    var obRight;
    var over = false;
    var iEdgeThreshold = 10;

    function findPos(obj) {
      var curleft = curtop = 0;
      if (obj.offsetParent) {
        curleft = obj.offsetLeft;
        curtop = obj.offsetTop;
        while (obj = obj.offsetParent) {
          curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
          curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        }
      }
      return [curleft, curtop];
    }

    /* Function that tells me if on the border or not */
    function isOnBorderRight(objTable, objTh, event) {
      var width = objTh.offsetWidth;
      var left = objTh.offsetLeft;
      var pos = findPos(objTable);
      var absRight = pos[0] + left + width;

      if (event.clientX > (absRight - iEdgeThreshold)) {
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    }

    function getNodeName(objReference, nodeName) {
      var oElement = objReference;
      while (oElement != null && oElement.tagName != null) {
        if (oElement.tagName == nodeName) {
          return oElement;
        }
        oElement = oElement.parentNode;
      }
      return null;
    }

    function doResize(objTh, event) {
      if (!event) event = window.event;
      var objTable = getNodeName(objTh, "TABLE");
      if (isOnBorderRight(objTable, objTh, event)) {
        over = true;
        objTh.style.cursor = "e-resize";
      } else {
        over = false;
        objTh.style.cursor = "";
      }
      return over;
    }

    function doneResizing() {
      over = false;
    }

    function MD(event) {//alert(event.srcElement.tagName+ " and "+event.target.tagName)
      if (!event) event = window.event;

      MOUSTSTART_X = event.clientX;
      MOUSTSTART_Y = event.clientY;
      
      if (over) {
        if (event.srcElement) ob = event.srcElement;
        else if (event.target) ob = event.target;
        else return;

        ob = getNodeName(ob, "TD");
        
        if (ob == null) {return;
        }
        //ob2 = getNodeName(ob,"TABLE");
        //obLeft = ob.previousSibling;
        obRight = ob.nextSibling;
        //obLeft = ob.previousElementSibling; 
        //obRight = ob.nextElementSibling;  // Uncomment For FF
        obwidth = parseInt(ob.style.width);
        if (obLeft != null)
          obLeftWidth = parseInt(obLeft.style.width);
        if (obRight != null)
          obRightWidth = parseInt(obRight.style.width);
        //obwidth2=parseInt(ob2.offsetWidth);
        
        alert(obRight+" and "+obwidth+" and "+obRightWidth);
      }
    }

    function MM(event) {
      if (!event) event = window.event;

      if (ob) {
        st = event.clientX - MOUSTSTART_X + obwidth;
        //st2=event.clientX-MOUSTSTART_X+obwidth2;
        document.getElementById("infoDiv").innerHTML = "st=" + st + " clientX=" + event.clientX + " moustart_x=" + MOUSTSTART_X + " obwidth=" + obwidth;
        //document.getElementById("infoDiv").innerHTML += ;
        //document.getElementById("infoDiv").innerHTML += ;
        //document.getElementById("infoDiv").innerHTML += obwidth;

        if (st >= 10) {
          ob.style.width = st;
          //ob2.style.width=st2;
          //obLeft.style.width=st-obLeftWidth;
          obRight.style.width = (parseInt(obwidth - st + obRightWidth) > 10 ? (obwidth - st + obRightWidth) : iEdgeThreshold + "px");
        }
        if (document.selection) document.selection.empty();
        else if (window.getSelection) window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
      }
    }

    function MU(event) {
      if (!event) event = window.event;
      if (ob) {
        if (document.selection) document.selection.empty();
        else if (window.getSelection) window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        ob = null;
      }
    }

    document.onmousedown = MD;
    document.onmousemove = MM;
    document.onmouseup = MU;
```

```css
html>body div.scrollable tbody {
            overflow: auto;
         }
  
         table.resizable th{
            text-align:center;
            overflow: hidden;
         }
  
         /* if mozilla, add 10 for the scrollbar */
         html>body th.scrollbarCol {
            width:10px;
         }
  
         table.resizable td{
            overflow: hidden;
         }
  
         table.resizable{
            table-layout:fixed;
         }
  
         table.resizable input{
            width:100%;
         }
  
         table.resizable textarea{
            width:100%;
         }
  
         .nowrap {
             white-space:nowrap;
         }
  
         /* needed for IE */
         table.tabular th.scrollbarCol {
            background-color:transparent; 
         }
  
         table.tabular {
            FONT-SIZE: 13px;
            FONT-FAMILY: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif';
            COLOR: #336699;
         }
  
         table.tabular thead {
             COLOR: #ffffff;
             FONT-WEIGHT: bold;
         }
  
         table.tabular th{
            background-color:#c0c0c0; 
            padding: 4px;
         }
  
         table.tabular td {
            background-color:#EAF4F3;
            padding: 2px;
         }
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
    <TABLE id="mytable" style="width:100%; table-layout:fixed" class="sortable resizable tabular">
      <THEAD>
        <TR>
          <td onmousemove="doResize(this,event)" onmouseover="doResize(this,event)" onmouseout='doneResizing()' style='width:60px'>Index</td>
          <td onmousemove="doResize(this,event)" onmouseover="doResize(this,event)" onmouseout='doneResizing()' style='width:170px'><span class="nowrap">Parameter Name</span></td>
          <td onmousemove="doResize(this,event)" onmouseover="doResize(this,event)" onmouseout='doneResizing()' style='width:170px'><span class="nowrap">Parameter Value</span></td>
          <td onmousemove="doResize(this,event)" onmouseover="doResize(this,event)" onmouseout='doneResizing()' style='width:110px'><span class="nowrap">Page Name</span></td>
        </TR>
      </THEAD>
      <TBODY style="height:200px">
        <TR>
          <Td>0</Td>
          <Td>1_2</Td>
          <Td>234</Td>
          <Td>1_3</Td>
        </TR>
      </TBODY>
    </table>
  </div>
  <span id="infoDiv"></span>
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Qmg4tZLITRIQHrY2nuuI?p=preview

Comment: You don't have any function calls to doResize() on the other td elements.

Comment: Done that. I didnt mention it in code. Its not working Here is the link http://plnkr.co/edit/u2a4MSFL0LTuKqDGyn9T?p=preview

Comment: I'm not sure I understand then, the link you provided seems to work for me. are you wanting to change the entire td width by dragging a td lower than the thead?

Comment: Try the second link. I mention the function call to every td but only first row td's will work. It should work for all td's

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when you pass 'this' in the second level of td's you're not traversing back up the dom enough to get to the thead td. I would try putting some id's to your first td elements so you can directly pass them to your function from your second tds.

EDIT:

I think this code is the issue:

```
  function getNodeName(objReference, nodeName) {
  var oElement = objReference;
  while (oElement != null && oElement.tagName != null) {
    if (oElement.tagName == nodeName) {
      return oElement;
    }
    oElement = oElement.parentNode;
  }
  return null;
}
```

When you call it from MD, you call like this:

```
ob = getNodeName(ob, "TD");
```

So when you enter getNodeName() and it gets to the if (oElement.tagName == nodeName) statement, it's eval to true and then exits the function. Then, when you do obRight = ob.nextsibling, it isn't working on the top-level td element like you want, it's working only on the bottom one. And I don't think you can set widths of those elements outside the tr in thead.

What I think you need is another check either in getNodeName() or MD() functions that identifies where you are in the DOM so you can get back to the top of the table, which is where you want to be to change the widths.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, without putting id, we cant do it?

Comment: I think you can, but your getNodeName() function will need to be modified to get back up to the correct parent node.

Comment: The issue seems to be that when you call getNodeName() from the MD() function, you're never getting to the part of the while loop that sets oElement = oElement.parentNode; You're passing "TD" to getNodName, and so your if statement evals to true and the function returns. You need to do an extra check to make sure you're getting the right parent element. Make sense?